# Controlling selection of one p:selectOneMenu from other p:selectOneMenu in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two `p:selectOneMenu`, one is Zone and other is District, if District is selected then it should automatically select the respective Zone, Both Zone and District are loaded from database table and District table contains Zone_id. i.e. Zone is accessible from District using zone_id.

Both Zone and District are loaded when the form is loaded.
How to implement this function in `Primefaces` ? I have done same stuff in Java but not in Primefaces.

Comment: I tried to read the district_id to get zone_id and then find the zone in the zone table but dunno how to display in the p:selectOneMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Mkyong's JSF 2 ValueChangeListener Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-valuechangelistener-example/). The `<p:selectOneMenu>` should work just like the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example as its working fine for we can use more than two selectOneMenu if we want which are dependable on one other

page.xhtml

```
   <h:outputLabel value="Country"></h:outputLabel>
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.countryId}" style="width:157px;">
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" />
           <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.countryList}" var="country"
               itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country.id}" />
           <p:ajax update="State" listener="#{someBean.coutChange}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>

   <h:outputLabel value="State"></h:outputLabel>
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{someBean.stateId}" id="State" style="width:157px;">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select State" itemValue="" />
          <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.stateList}" var="state"
             itemLabel="#{state.name}" itemValue="#{state.id}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
```

In Bean class use to array list of type object in your database and create getter/setters and in getter write queries to get data from data base. Create variables for selected values from the selectOneMenu use that variable for value attribute for selectOneMenu tag. Then in the p:ajax tag for the listener write a method to check coutryId is null if not return list of states based on countryId. This should work hope it helps you